# make math operation from multiple files with shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, redhat

I have multiple files, let's say

`fname1` contains:

```
red=5
green=10
yellow=2
```

`fname2` contains:

```
red=10
green=2
yellow=2
```

`fname3` contains:

```
red=1
green=7
yellow=4
```

I want to write script that read from these files, sum the numbers for each colour,
and redirect the sums into new file.

New file contains:

```
red=16
green=19
yellow=8
```

Comment: This sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: Use `awk`. Use the color as the key of an array, and add the number to the array value. At the end print all the array elements.

Comment: it's required from m in the work, i work on redhat server and i have these three files contains this variables, so i wanna write bash script to make math operation on the files and redirect the sum to new file ,,,thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[ awk ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is your friend :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}
            {color[$1]+=$2}
     END{
         for(var in color)
          printf "%s=%s\n",var,color[var]
        }' fname1 fname2 fname3 >result
```

should do it.

---

**Demystifying above stuff**

- Anything that is include inside `''` is the awk program.
- Stuff inside `BEGIN` will be executed only once, ie in the beginning
- FS is an awk built-in variable which stands for field separator.
- Setting FS to `=` means awk will use `=` to delimit the fields/columns.
- By default `awk` considers each line as a record.
- In that case you have two fields denoted by $1 and $2 in each record having `=` as the delimiter.
- `{color[$1]+=$2}` creates(if not already exist) an associative array with color name as the `key` and `+=` adds the `value` of the field2 to this array element. Remember, associative arrays at the time of creation are initilized to zero.
- This is repeated for the three files fname1, fname2, fname3 fed into awk
- Anything inside `END{}` will be executed only at last, ie just before exit.
- `for(var in color)` is a the style of forloop used to parse an associative array.
- Here `var` will be a `key` and `color[key]` points to value.
- `printf "%s=%s\n",var,color[var]` is self explained.

**Note**

- If all the filenames start with `fname` you can even put `fname*` instead of `fname1 fname2 fname3`
- This assumes that there are no blank lines in any file

Comment: thanks for your help ,but when i tried it i recieved the foolowing error                                                                        awk: cmd. line:6:         }
awk: cmd. line:6:         ^ syntax error

Comment: @p.louis : Corrected,When I formatted the code an extra `}` creeped in after `color[var]` ;) Sorry abt that

Comment: Great job ! You made it look like a piece of cake.

Comment: @sjsam thanks a lot dear it's solved it really many thanks, please could you explain this code to me because i don't understand it

Comment: @mona_sax: Thanks. Like somebody said here, there is no `hard nut` for  `awk`  ;)

Comment: @p.louis No problem, I will add some explanation :)

Comment: @sjsam Thanks a lot you deserve all the best for your great work and attitude :)

Comment: @p.louis : If you wish to become an expert with `awk` try going thru a book called `Effective AWK Programming` by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

Because your source files are valid shell code. You can just source them (if they are from a trusted source) and accumulate them using  [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sum_red=0
sum_green=0
sum_yellow=0

for file in "$@";do
    . ${file}
    let sum_red+=red
    let sum_green+=green
    let sum_yellow+=yellow
done

echo "red=$sum_red
green=$sum_green
yellow=$sum_yellow"
```

Comment: thanks a lot,, but when i tried it it's print red=0 green=0 yellow=0 not the sum

Comment: You have to supply you input files as arguments: `./sum.sh frame*`

Comment: thanks a lot dear for you help i tried it but it's appear wrong sum, it's solved with @sjsam code